# CSS toggle switch group of several buttons

Tags: css, html

I'd like something like the [JQuery Mobile Flip Toggle Switch](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/forms/switch/options.html), but just that, then I don't want to load all the JQuery Mobile library into my project.

Do you know how to do a nice CSS toggle buttons (more of 2 buttons) like these? I didn't find anything.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

PS: I don't care about compability with IE.

Comment: You mean like https://ghinda.net/css-toggle-switch/?

Comment: thos on off switches are pretty bad IMO, I'm using a mouse on a screen not my finger tip to flick a switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did something quickly. Hope it will help you.

```css
ul.tab {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
ul.tab li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.tab li label {
  background: white;  
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.tab li input[type="radio"] {
    opacity: 0;
    width:1px;
    height:1px;
}
ul.tab li input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tab">
    <li>
        <input id="tab1" checked="checked" type="radio" name="tab" />
        <label for="tab1">Basic</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tab" />
        <label for="tab2">Options</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tab" />
        <label for="tab3">Methods</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tab" />
        <label for="tab4">Events</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```